Craft Commerce 5: Dynamically Update Variant Price and Stock
Just before the payment step, I need to check the prices and quantities of the products in the cart.
The reason is that we use an external database (physical store) where prices and quantities are adjusted regularly. Before proceeding with the payment, I need to verify that this data is up to date, and if necessary, modify it.
Here’s what I’m trying to do:
if ((float) $priceToCompare !== (float) $commercePrice) {
    // Load the variant directly
    $variant = Commerce::getInstance()->getVariants()->getVariantById($lineItem->purchasable->id);

    if ($variant) {
        // Set the new price and save the variant
        $variant->price = (float) $priceToCompare;
        Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($variant);
    }
}

The problem is that, although the variant is correctly retrieved, the price is never updated.
It seems like Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($variant) is not working, even though the new price is correctly assigned to $variant->price.
Additionally, I am also trying to update the stock of the variant. However, when attempting to set $variant->stock, I get the following error:
Invalid Call – yii\base\InvalidCallException
Setting read-only property: craft\commerce\elements\Variant::stock

How can I resolve these issues? How can I dynamically update both the price and stock just before payment?

If you want to update the variants price you will need to be setting the basePrice property on the variant model before saving it.
You will also need to make sure the cart is being recalculated after you have made these changes.
